# for loop won't run inside while loop java

Tags: java

There's a while loop in my program that will loop infinitely because the for loop inside won't run twice. I want to find the number of combinations that will have a sum of 4 from input and here's my code:

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
int n = scan.nextInt();

ArrayList<Integer> taxi = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
  taxi.add(scan.nextInt());
}

int i = 0;
int total=0;
int tax=0;
int num = 0;
while (num<n) {
  i=0;
  for (i=0; i<n; i++) {
    if (total+taxi.get(i)<=4) {
      total+=taxi.get(i);
      System.out.println(total);
      num++;
    }
  }
  tax++;
}
System.out.println("Taxis= " + tax);
```

Comment: Now is a good time to learn how to use a debugger.  Really.  You need to step through each line of code, examine the variable values, and see the behavior.  Learning to debug is just as important as learning the language.

Comment: Or put few `System.out.println()` ;-)

Comment: Or you remove the num++ from inside the if condition... If the condition not true, it will not inc and it's game over...

Answer (score 0):

looking though you're code it seems your issue lies in the usage of some of your variables such as I multiple times which causes the code to not compile. try using better names or more unique names in order to prevent these issues in future. as well as that I would also advise not zeroing all of your variables so often in such a manner. Finally your issue has to do with your usage of the variable n as it remains a fixed number which will not change in the while loop meaning it will always be true. the best way to fix this is to utilize the

```
break;
```

command to exit the while loop or to use a counted loop like a for loop.
In my honest opinion i would request that when asking these questions next time check all the variables with a print line in the appropriate spot.